# How to reindex a datetime-based multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe that counts the number of times an event has occured per user per day. Users may have 0 events per day and (since the table is an aggregate from a raw event log) rows with 0 events are missing from the dataframe. I would like to add these missing rows and group the data by week so that each user has one entry per week (including 0 if applicable).

Here is an example of my input:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "person_id": np.arange(3).repeat(5),
    "date": pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-01-15", freq="d"),
    "event_count": np.random.randint(1, 7, 15),
})

# end of each week
# Note: week 2022-01-23 is not in df, but should be part of the result
desired_index = pd.to_datetime(["2022-01-02", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-16", "2022-01-23"])

df
```

```
|    |   person_id | date                |   event_count |
|---:|------------:|:--------------------|--------------:|
|  0 |           0 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |             4 |
|  1 |           0 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |             5 |
|  2 |           0 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 |             3 |
|  3 |           0 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 |             5 |
|  4 |           0 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 |             5 |
|  5 |           1 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 |             2 |
|  6 |           1 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 |             3 |
|  7 |           1 | 2022-01-08 00:00:00 |             3 |
|  8 |           1 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |             3 |
|  9 |           1 | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 |             5 |
| 10 |           2 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00 |             4 |
| 11 |           2 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 |             3 |
| 12 |           2 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 |             6 |
| 13 |           2 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 |             5 |
| 14 |           2 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00 |             2 |
```

This is how my desired result looks like:

```
|    |   person_id | level_1             |   event_count |
|---:|------------:|:--------------------|--------------:|
|  0 |           0 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |             9 |
|  1 |           0 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |            13 |
|  2 |           0 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |             0 |
|  3 |           0 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 |             0 |
|  4 |           1 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |             0 |
|  5 |           1 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |            11 |
|  6 |           1 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |             5 |
|  7 |           1 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 |             0 |
|  8 |           2 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |             0 |
|  9 |           2 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |             0 |
| 10 |           2 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |            20 |
| 11 |           2 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 |             0 |
```

I can produce it using:

```py
(
    df
    .groupby(["person_id", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="w")]).sum()
    .groupby("person_id").apply(
        lambda df: (
            df
            .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
            .reindex(desired_index, fill_value=0))
        )
    .reset_index()
)
```

However, according to the docs of [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), I should be able to use it with `level=1` as a kwarg directly and without having to do another `groupby`. However, when I do this I get an "inner join" of the two indices instead of an "outer join":

```py
result = (
    df
    .groupby(["person_id", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="w")]).sum()
    .reindex(desired_index, level=1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

```
|    |   person_id | date                |   event_count |
|---:|------------:|:--------------------|--------------:|
|  0 |           0 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |             9 |
|  1 |           0 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |            13 |
|  2 |           1 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 |            11 |
|  3 |           1 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |             5 |
|  4 |           2 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |            20 |
```

Why is that, and how am I supposed to use `df.reindex` correctly?

---

I have found [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953517/reindex-specific-level-of-pandas-multiindex) on reindexing a multi-index level, but the accepted answer there uses `df.unstack`, which doesn't work for me, because not every level of my desired index occurs in my current index (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need reindex by both levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['person_id'].unique(), desired_index], 
                                 names=['person_id','date'])
result = (
    df
    .groupby(["person_id", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="w")]).sum()
    .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)
print (result)
    person_id       date  event_count
0           0 2022-01-02            9
1           0 2022-01-09           13
2           0 2022-01-16            0
3           0 2022-01-23            0
4           1 2022-01-02            0
5           1 2022-01-09           11
6           1 2022-01-16            5
7           1 2022-01-23            0
8           2 2022-01-02            0
9           2 2022-01-09            0
10          2 2022-01-16           20
11          2 2022-01-23            0
```

Comment: You avoid using `.reindex(level=1, ...)` here, too. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger - You can check discussion - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12319

Comment: Suggestion: the answer could clarify that `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` computes the Cartesian product of the iterables, hence giving all possible combinations. This is a key point to answer the question.